# Building a matrix of 'rolled' rows efficiently in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'd like to construct a `(n,n)`-array from a one dimensional array, where each row is shifted (with wrapping) by one relative to the previous one. The following code does this:

```
import numpy as np

r = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
n = len(r)
MM = np.zeros((n, n), dtype=r.dtype)
for k in range(n):
    MM[k, :] = np.roll(r, k)

print(MM)
```

which results in:

```
[[1 2 3 4 5]
 [5 1 2 3 4]
 [4 5 1 2 3]
 [3 4 5 1 2]
 [2 3 4 5 1]]
```

Is there a way to do this Numpy faster, i.e., avoiding the `for`-loop, for large `r` in Numpy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [`scipy.linalg.circulant`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.circulant.html)

```
In [255]: r
Out[255]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

In [256]: circulant(r).T
Out[256]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [5, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [4, 5, 1, 2, 3],
       [3, 4, 5, 1, 2],
       [2, 3, 4, 5, 1]])
```

or [`scipy.linalg.toeplitz`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.toeplitz.html)

```
In [257]: toeplitz(np.roll(r[::-1], 1), r)
Out[257]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [5, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [4, 5, 1, 2, 3],
       [3, 4, 5, 1, 2],
       [2, 3, 4, 5, 1]])
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the answer I was hoping for.