# efficient way to generate 2 dimensional array of multiple shifts of a 1 dimensional array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Consider the array `a`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed([3,1415])
a = np.random.randint(100, size=10)
print(a)

[11 98 74 90 15 55 13 11 13 26]
```

I want to build an array of increasing shifted versions of this array that looks like this.  I want a generalize way to do this for an arbitrary number of shifts less than the length of the original array.  In this case, the number of shifts `n` is equal to `5`

```
[[ 11.  nan  nan  nan  nan]
 [ 98.  11.  nan  nan  nan]
 [ 74.  98.  11.  nan  nan]
 [ 90.  74.  98.  11.  nan]
 [ 15.  90.  74.  98.  11.]
 [ 55.  15.  90.  74.  98.]
 [ 13.  55.  15.  90.  74.]
 [ 11.  13.  55.  15.  90.]
 [ 13.  11.  13.  55.  15.]
 [ 26.  13.  11.  13.  55.]]
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37762904/building-a-matrix-of-rolled-rows-efficiently-in-numpy

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Actually, I forgot to put that in my question.  I was going to ask if this was a dup, please mark it.  I couldn't figure out what to search for.  I'm glad you did, thank you.

Comment: Another one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18026541/make-special-diagonal-matrix-in-numpy. Once you know the name, `toeplitz`, it is easy to search for related questions.  Without knowing the name, it is hard to find the right search terms that will yield relevant results.

Comment: I'm compiling these to fit my exact criteria and will add them to my testing.  More for my curiosity than anything.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser do you think `np.nan` and the performance aspect justify this not being a dup?  Either way, I'm fine with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I thought of two ways to do this

## use a generator

```
def multi_shift(a, n):
    yield a
    while n > 1:
        a = np.append(np.nan, a[:-1])
        yield a
        n -= 1

np.stack(multi_shift(a, 5)).T
```

## build a slice with broadcasting

```
rng = np.arange(len(a))
slc = rng[:, None] - rng[:5]

np.where(slc >= 0, a[slc], np.nan)
```

---

```
[[ 11.  nan  nan  nan  nan]
 [ 98.  11.  nan  nan  nan]
 [ 74.  98.  11.  nan  nan]
 [ 90.  74.  98.  11.  nan]
 [ 15.  90.  74.  98.  11.]
 [ 55.  15.  90.  74.  98.]
 [ 13.  55.  15.  90.  74.]
 [ 11.  13.  55.  15.  90.]
 [ 13.  11.  13.  55.  15.]
 [ 26.  13.  11.  13.  55.]]
```

---

***time testing***
***code***
[Divakar's `stride` functions from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41520385/2336654)

```
from scipy.linalg import toeplitz
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided as strided 

def pir1(a, n):
    return np.stack(multi_shift(a, n)).T

def pir2(a, n):
    rng = np.arange(len(a))
    slc = rng[:, None] - rng[:5]

    return np.where(slc >= 0, a[slc], np.nan)

# Suggested by @WarrenWeckesser
def toeplitz1(a, n):
    return toeplitz(a, np.array([np.nan] * n))

# from @Divakar
def strided_nan_filled(a, W):
    a_ext = np.concatenate((np.full(W-1, np.nan), a))
    n = a_ext.strides[0]
    out = strided(a_ext, shape=(a.size, W), strides=(n, n))[:,::-1]
    return out

def strided_nan_filled_v2(a, W):
    a_ext = np.concatenate(( np.full(W-1,np.nan) ,a))
    n = a_ext.strides[0]
    return strided(a_ext[W-1:], shape=(a.size,W), strides=(n,-n))
```

***trials***

```
from timeit import timeit

cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [['pir1', 'pir2', 'toeplitz1', 'stride'], [10, 100]])
results = pd.DataFrame(index=[100, 1000], columns=cols)

np.random.seed([3,1415])
for i in results.index:
    a = np.random.rand(i)
    for j in results.columns:
        stmt = '{}(a, {})'.format(*j)
        iprt = 'from __main__ import a, {}'.format(j[0])
        results.set_value(i, j, timeit(stmt, iprt, number=100))

results.stack().plot.barh()
```

[image]

---

***Drop `pri1` and `toeplitz`***
Clearly those take too long
This look leaves no doubt `stride` is the way to go.

```
from timeit import timeit

cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [['pir2', 'strided_nan_filled', 'strided_nan_filled_v2'], [10, 100]])
results = pd.DataFrame(index=[100, 1000, 10000], columns=cols)

np.random.seed([3,1415])
for i in results.index:
    a = np.random.rand(i)
    for j in results.columns:
        stmt = '{}(a, {})'.format(*j)
        iprt = 'from __main__ import a, {}'.format(j[0])
        results.set_value(i, j, timeit(stmt, iprt, number=100))

results.stack().plot.barh()
```

[image]

Comment: updated.  feel free to edit.